# kotlin Generic type function as parameters

Tags: generics, kotlin, lambda

i stuck in some problems about the `generic` type in kotlin. Originally,i want to call the function with the value and the recall-function. So i write that below, but the value only allows me pass a type like string/Int  somethings like that. I want to pass a function as parameter in the recall function.

ClassA

```
ClassA<T>{
var canCancel: Boolean = true
var recallFunction: (() -> T)? = null
var recallFunctionWithValue: ((value: T) -> Unit)? = null
var context: Context? = null
var value: T? = null
var functionPara :( ()->T)? = null
var recallFunctionWithFunction:((()->T) -> Unit)? = null

constructor(context: Context?, canCancel: Boolean, value: T, recallFunctionWithValue: (value: T) -> Unit) {
this.context = context
this.canCancel = canCancel
this.value = value
this.recallFunctionWithValue = recallFunctionWithValue
}
}
```

ClassB

```
ClassA(ctx, true,viewModel!!::testRefInside,viewModel!!::testRefOutside).createNativeNetworkDialog()
```

ViewModel

```
fun testRefOutside(test: Observable<Any>? ){

}
fun testRefInside():Observable<Any>?{
    return null
}
```

---

i try to do something like that

```
var canCancel: Boolean = true
var recallFunction: (() -> T)? = null
var recallFunctionWithValue: ((value: T) -> Unit)? = null
var context: Context? = null
var value: T? = null
var functionPara :( ()->T)? = null
var recallFunctionWithFunction:((()->T) -> Unit)? = null

    constructor(context: Context?, canCancel: Boolean, value: () -> T, recallFunctionWithValue: (value: ()->T) -> Unit) {
    this.context = context
    this.canCancel = canCancel
    this.functionPara = value
    this.recallFunctionWithFunction = recallFunctionWithValue
}
```

but it shows the syntax error. Can someone help?

Syntax Error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNyqF.png)

[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4DcD.png)

[Error show in this place only RYEasyDialog means ClassA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAWN9.png)

---

It works!! now

```
  var recallFunctionWithFunction:((value: T) -> Unit)? = null
    constructor(context: Context?, canCancel: Boolean, value: () -> T, recallFunctionWithValue: (value: T) -> Unit) {
    this.context = context
    this.canCancel = canCancel
    this.functionPara = value
    this.recallFunctionWithFunction = recallFunctionWithValue
```

### }

**8/6 Updated** Vararg problems

I am doing something in advanced. I just post it in completed code.
If i don't use vararg , the

```
EasyDialog<Observable<Any>,LiveData<Boolean>>(ctx, true,viewModel!!::callGetTeammateListAPITEST,recallFunctionWithFunction = viewModel!!::callMultipleAPI).createNativeNetworkDialog2()
```

without casting `as ((Observable<Any>)->LiveData<Boolean>)`
.but the callMuipleApi receives vararg parameter, i have to cast it into as ((Observable)->LiveData) but i it doesn't show any error but the function callmutipleapi and callgetteammateslist in not called.
can anyone help?

ViewModel

```
fun callMultipleAPI( vararg  observable: Observable<Any>):LiveData<Boolean>{
    if(progressDialogData==null){
        progressDialogData= MutableLiveData()
    }
    progressDialogData?.setValue(true)
    repo.callMultipleAPI<Any>(*observable, observer = RYEasyObserver(object : RyObserverSingleStatusListener<List<Any>> {
        override fun onNext(g: List<Any>) {
            Log.d("test",g.toString())
            for(model in g){
                when(model){
                    is GetTeammateListModel ->{setCallGetTeammateListResponse(model)}
                    is GetTeamListModel ->{setCallGetTeamListResponse(model)}
                    is GetMessageSumModel->{setCallGetMessageSumResponse(model)}
                    is GetCallModel->{setCallGetResponse(model)}
                }
            }
            progressDialogData?.setValue(false)
        }


        override fun onError() {
            progressDialogData?.setValue(false)
        }

    },true))
    return progressDialogData!!
}
```

Fragment

```
EasyDialog<Observable<Any>,LiveData<Boolean>>(ctx, true,viewModel!!::callGetTeammateListAPITEST,recallFunctionWithFunction = viewModel!!::callMultipleAPI as ((Observable<Any>)->LiveData<Boolean>)).createNativeNetworkDialog2()
```

EasyDialog

```
class EasyDialog<T,V> {
var canCancel: Boolean = true
var recallFunction: (() -> T)? = null
var recallFunctionWithValue: ((value: T) -> Unit)? = null
var context: Context? = null
var value: T? = null
var functionPara :(()->T)? = null
var recallFunctionWithFunction:((T) -> V)? = null



    constructor(
    context: Context?, canCancel: Boolean, value: ()->T, recallFunctionWithFunction:  (T) -> V  ){
    this.context = context
    this.canCancel = canCancel
    this.functionPara = value
    this.recallFunctionWithFunction = recallFunctionWithFunction
}
    fun createNativeNetworkDialog2() {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    if (!canCancel) {
        builder.setCancelable(false)
    } else {
        builder.setNegativeButton(context?.resources?.getString(R.string.gloda_cancel)) { dialogInterface, id -> }
    }
    builder.setMessage(context?.resources?.getString(R.string.global_network_error))
    builder.setPositiveButton(context?.resources?.getString(R.string.global_retry)) { dialog, id ->
        recallFunction?.invoke()
        value?.let { it1 -> recallFunctionWithValue?.invoke(it1) }
        //functionPara?.let { it2->recallFunctionWithFunction?.invoke(it2) }
        functionPara?.let{ functionPara->{ recallFunctionWithFunction?.let {
                recallFunctionWithFunction-> compose<T,V>(recallFunctionWithFunction  ,functionPara).invoke()
        }}}
    }

    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}
    fun <T, V> compose( f: (T) -> V,    g:() -> T ): () -> V {
            return {  f(g()) }
}
```

Comment: Need to see the first line of each of your classes to see how you defined the generic type and how you defined your primary constructor, if any. And what does the syntax error say?

Comment: This `recallFunctionWithValue: (value: ()->T) -> Unit` is probably giving the error. You cannot have names in function types. What you probably want is `(() -> T) -> Unit` or something like that

Comment: I have updated the error message and show clearly about the declaration.

Comment: @user, that's just not true. You can name function type parameters.

Comment: I still can't tell where your error is. Do you get the error when trying to call the constructor, or is it in your constructor definition? What line is the error marked on?  The line `this.recallFunctionWithFunction = recallFunctionWithValue` because the names don't match, but you actually do have a parameter with a matching name `recallFunctionWithValue`.

Comment: And we still need to see your class definition line to see how you defined what `T` is.

Comment: i have re-edited the updated where error occupy.

Comment: I just define like that
class ClassA<T>{
....
}

Comment: @Tenfour04 I was talking about how the OP attempted to give the name `value` to one of the parameters (not a type parameter) of the type of the function `recallFunctionWithValue` by doing `recallFunctionWithValue: (value: ()->T) -> Unit`

Comment: i have updated the advanced problems !! can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last constructor parameter is

```
(() -> T) -> Unit
```

Based on what you pass for the third constructor paramter, `T` is inferred to be `Observable<Any>?`. so it is expecting a

```
(() -> Observable<Any>?) -> Unit
```

but `testRefOutside` is

```
 Observable<Any>? -> Unit
```

I'm guessing you probably didn't mean to define a third-order function by making the input of your function another function.

Comment: It depends what you are using these functions for. This class looks convoluted, so I can't tell just by looking, but probably you want to change the last constructor parameter type to `T -> Unit`, and do the same to whichever property you are assigning it to.

Comment: Your class would be much simpler by defining the properties in a primary constructor and avoiding nullables and read-write `vars` wherever possible.

Comment: I want to pass one function with returning a observable<Any> as a parameter into another function .In this situation, I want to put the testRefInside as a parameter into testRefOutside. However,i still have no idea how to do it.

Comment: value?.let { it1 -> recallFunctionWithValue?.invoke(it1) }  The Original one with parameter with only T type and it works!!
but  i want to do like this,
functionPara?.let { it1 -> recallFunctionWithFunction?.invoke(it1) }

Comment: i have updated the new question can anyone help ?  i solved the problems with testRefOuside and inside, but the advanced problem is about the vararg parameter

Comment: Did you really just change the question and remove your acceptance of the answer to the original question?